# регулярное выражение с совпадающим шаблоном

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить строку на два вхождения одинакового шаблона.
Например

```
if (/([abc][xyz])([abc][xyz])/) {
    do_something;
}
```

Проблема в том, что нужно, чтобы это соответсвовало строкам `axay`, `bybz`, но строке `axax` соответствовать не должно. Т.е что-то вроде:

```
if (/([abc][xyz])([abc][xyz])/) {
    do_something unless $1 eq $2;
}
```

Пример на Перле, но это не принципиально, вообще нужен скорее синтаксис Qt (C++). Т.е. можно ли 2-ой пример кода реализовать в виде одной регулярки, без второго `if`'а?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант с использованием [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
([abc][xyz])(?!\1)([abc][xyz])
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/zQ6eM8/1).

Comment: Как просто. Спасибо огромное, ответ получен.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Вы можете помечать удовлетворивший Вас ответ с помощью галочки слева от ответа.